# How to assign password to ConnectionString programatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I have `ConnectionString` defined in `App.config` file and I check the option not to include sensitive data so the password is left out from the connection string. In the application code I'm using Entity Framework and I'm accessing the db like this:

```
using (var db = new Entities())  
{                
     List<DATA> d = db.DATA.ToList();
}
```

I want authenticate user by the DB password - user enters it when the application launches.
The question is, how to add this password to the connection string when I don't handle the `ConnectionString` manually in the code?

The farther I got is this:

```
ConnectionStringSettings conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"];
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(conn.ConnectionString);
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);
sqlBuilder.Password = "pwd";
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();            
ConnectionStringSettings newConn = new ConnectionStringSettings("Entities",entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
```

But this still does not work and I cannot assing the new connection string to the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` - it says it is read only value. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` because that just reflects your `App.config`, which your app can't change.

But you can tell the EF which connection string to use:

```
using (var db = new Entities(entityBuilder.ToString()))  
{                
     List<DATA> d = db.DATA.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought so too originally but got confused by the fact that the Entities class generated by the framework does not provide any such constructor and now I see that there is one provided by base DbContext class which is overshadowed. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Well, my derived classes have those constructors, so I'm not sure why you're not seeing them.